# How to reprint the C++ print request file

Tags: c++

If personal information is included in the requested print using C++ language, cancel the current print and print again after receiving approval from the server.

※This event is raised when the user directly outputs an open file.
(In other words, if the user directly requests printing of an open file in the same way as ctrl+p, printing will be requested for the open file because the dll I created works.)

Approval is at EndDoc, the point at which the print is almost finished.

The problematic part is how to print again.

I was using the implementation to request a print again as shown below.

[refer to variable]

1. RequestDevModeW -> When printing is requested for the first time, the information is saved and used for reprint. (Saved when calling DocumentPropertiesW API.)
2. RequestDOCInfoW -> When printing is requested for the first time, the information is saved and used for reprint. (This is a structure stored in StartDocW when requesting a print for the first time.)
3. nPageCnt -> The number of startpage <-> Endpage is stored when the first print request is made.

[Code]

```
//... skip ...//
hReprintDC = CreateDCW(NULL, wszPrintName, NULL, &RequestDevModeW);

if (hReprintDC)
{
    RequestDOCInfoW.lpszDocName = (LPCWSTR)wszDocName;

    StartDocW(hReprintDC, &RequestDOCInfoW);
    for (int nPage = 0; nPage < nPageCnt; ++nPage)
    {
    StartPage(hReprintDC);
    EndPage(hReprintDC);
    }
    EndDoc(hReprintDC);

    DeleteDC(hReprintDC);
    g_hRePrintDC = NULL;
}
//... skip ...//
```

However, the code above is causing an error when displaying textbox in some documents (excel, word).

So I used the ShellExecuteEX API.
It prints very well, but I can't get the print attributes to work.
What I mean by print properties is that you have no control over these details, such as printing specific pages.

I'm curious about how to make a detailed request for a print using C++ code.
In addition, the print dialog should be output as it is with the existing specifications without being displayed.